# How reliable is bluetooth on Android phones?

Tags: android, bluetooth, libgdx

How reliable is bluetooth on Android?
I have written a draft game with bluetooth on Libgdx.
But 25% of packets disappear.
So movements of actors are jerky.
Then I add confirmation for received packets.
But it slows down the performance.
Sometimes packets are resending few times.
The devices are just near each other.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were the case then file transfer between two devices might never be successful since you will never get the complete file on other side.

What matters is what [BT Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) you implement.

The [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Human_Interface_Device_Profile_.28HID.29) is used for gaming mouse, keyboard etc.

But most android phones, atleast sometime back didnt have HID profile implemented ,had some experience with samsung mobile phones but tablets may be different I guess.

Comment: What maybe the reason of unreliable work in my game? As I said I lost 25% of sent packets

Comment: can you show your code as of how are you making connections and transmitting data.

Comment: The code is rather big, and I doubt that someone would like to research it. The idea of code is as follows. I took Bluetooth Chat Google's example. After establishing connection, user should tap the "play" button and Activity2 starts, where I start Libgdx thread.Unfortunately I could not find other bluetooth  examples. Only Google's Chat.

Comment: If bluetooth is reliable then why is OBEX adopted by bluetooth?"Wikipedia says OBEX is similar in design and function to HTTP in providing the client with a reliable transport for connecting to a server and may then request or provide objects.Can u please explain

Comment: OBEX is protocol that is used for communication and Bluetooth is medium for it. Protocols are similar to language , lets suppose I want to talk to you on Stackoverflow,so I will  use English,if I try using Japanese or you use French then there will be no successful communication . So here OBEX is just a language that is used for communication via Bluetooth(which is medium like stackoverflow). @Kozlov

Comment: thank you, experiment am trying to do is am writing bulk to f 64k continuously to a Bluetooth output-stream and on the other side am just reading and write into a file .after complete transfer when i compare the files the byte received is less on receiving size.When I compare the files in a file comparision tool I see that some bytes in between is missed.So wonder is BT reliable on is it something like there is a buffer in bt stack and its getting overwritten?